# What would be the best way to write this query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in my database that has 1.1MM records. I have another table in my database that has about 2000 records under the field name, "NAME". What I want to do is do a search from Table 1 using the smaller table and pull the records where they match the smaller tables record. For example Table 1 has First Name, Last Name. Table 2 has Name, I want to find every record in Table 1 that contains any of Table 2 Names in either the first name field or the second name field. I tried just making an access query but my computer just froze. Any thoughts would be appreaciated.

Comment: Minor quibble, but one that can cause incredible headaches if you disregard it: NAME is a reserved word in Access and should never be used as a field or object name.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered the following:

```
Select Table1.FirstName, Table1.LastName 
from Table1 
where EXISTS(Select * from Table2 WHERE Name = Table1.FirstName) 
   or EXISTS(Select * from Table2 WHERE Name = Table1.LastName)
```

I have found before that on large tables this might work better than an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to create indexes on Table1.first_name, Table1.last_name, and Table2.name.  They will dramatically speed up your query.

Edit: For Microsoft Access 2007, see [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177891.aspx).

Comment: Wow, that almost always happens to me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See above previous notes about indexes, but I believe from your description,  you want something like:

```
select table1.* from table1 
  inner join 
    table2 on (table1.first_name = table2.name OR table1.last_name = table2.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should go something like this,

```
Select Table1.FirstName, Table1.LastName 
from Table1 
where Table1.FirstName IN (Select Distinct Name from Table2) 
   or Table1.LastName  IN (Select Distinct Name from Table2)
```

And there are various other ways to run this same query, i would suggest you see execution plan for each of these queries to find out which one is the fastest. In addition creating indexes on the column which is used in a "where" condition will also speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with **astander**. based on my experience, using EXIST instead of IN is a lot faster.